# warning: 'virtual void wxWindowBase::SetInitialBaseSize(const wxSize&)' is deprecated

Tags: c++, codeblocks, wxwidgets

I have just solved a wxWidget error of lwxmwsu31u.a is not found in codeBlocks and when trying to build and run my first c++ wxwidget example i get this warning "warning:  'virtual void wxWindowBase::SetInitialBaseSize(const wxSize&)' is deprecated", there are about 245 warnings and i don't know how to solve them. Please help.

Comment: I would say that the warning you show is pretty obvious. The function which you try to use is deprecated, and you should migrate to other functions. I suggest you read the documentation for that function to see what it says. As for the rest of the warnings, unless it's the same (use of deprecated functions) then we can't help you unless you show them to us, together with a [**Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that leads to those warnings.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is telling you that the method you are trying to call is no longer used by the library. Therefore the compiler cannot link with it.
The [wxWindow class reference](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_window.html) does not mention your function call either.
Instead, try using

```html
wxWindow::SetInitialSize (const wxSize &size=wxDefaultSize)
```

It is very likely that 1 of your 245 warning is telling you to use SetInitialSize instead.

Comment: Where do i exactly change that, i am quite new to this

Comment: wxWindow is a part of wxWidgets, a GUI library which lets you create windows and such. You can find more information [on the wxWidgets website](https://www.wxwidgets.org). But apperently you haven't written that code yourself. Try the suggestion by Ripi2 below. Then the next question is: what version of GCC are you using, and if it is lower than version 5.3, it suggest you update it since it's quite old (2015)

Comment: Of course i have found i am using GCC 5.1.0, i am trying to upgrade to the latest, though it's a bit messy, do you know a simpler way

Comment: You could also downgrade to an older version of wxWidgets, but i wouldn't recommend that. Upgrading GCC seems the way to go here

Comment: I would like to upgrade, can you help me to know a way to upgrade gcc in windows 10 computer.

Comment: You can download the installers [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/mirrors.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue for **MinGW GCC compiler version < 5.3** (related to "assert" implementation).

A workaround is editing `yourWxDir/include/wx/window.h`:

Go down about 1740 lines, until you see

```
wxDEPRECATED_MSG("use SetInitialSize() instead.") 
void SetBestSize(const wxSize& size); 
wxDEPRECATED_MSG("use SetInitialSize() instead.")
virtual void SetInitialBestSize(const wxSize& size);
```

Replace last two lines (the second wxDEPRECATED_MSG) with

```
#if !wxCHECK_GCC_VERSION(5, 0)
    wxDEPRECATED_MSG("use SetInitialSize() instead.")
#endif
virtual void SetInitialBestSize(const wxSize& size);
```

If you have built wxWidgets on your own (instead of a prebuilt download) then please rebuild it again.

If you use precompiled headers then delete `.pch` files and rebuild your app.

Comment: When i try your solution it works but the warnings reduce to 233 and i get a window saying "Run time error, this application has requested the Runtime to terminate in an unusual way Please contact the applicant's  support team for more information"

Comment: And most of the warnings if not all say "duplicate section: .'rdata$_ZTV20wxThreadHelperThread[ZTV20wxThreadHelperThread]' has... "

Comment: I downloaded the .exe files from wxWidgets website, after running the .exe files i then put some commands to cmd and it took couple of hours to finish. So what should i do. I had a couple of errors after iinstallation like configuration error

Comment: For problems about installation and building, please write a new question, showing all the steps you did and the command lines used.

Comment: Sorry for this but what i wanted to know was which among the two last lines i should do according to my installation of wxWidgets